# Occurrence of a string inside another string

Tags: php, sql, mariadb-10.4

I was wondering if there is an easy way to look for a occurrence of a string inside another string. I'm using this query:

```php
$nameId = "SELECT 
`testresults`.`id` AS TRid, requirementId, TestCaseId, TestSuiteCollectionId, TestSuiteId, TestSuiteCollectionName, `testcaserequirement`.`nameId` AS `Requirement`
FROM
testresultrequirementlink
    LEFT JOIN
`testresults` ON `testresultrequirementlink`.`testresultId` = `testresults`.`id`
LEFT JOIN
`testsuitecollection` ON `testresults`.`TestSuiteCollectionId` = `testsuitecollection`.`id`
LEFT JOIN
`testcaserequirement` ON `testresultrequirementlink`.`requirementId` = `testcaserequirement`.`id`
WHERE `TestSuiteCollectionName` LIKE '%".$checkfileName[0]."%'
GROUP BY `testresultrequirementlink`.`requirementId`;";
```

`$checkfileName[0]` will be set in a if-statement, where it's set to `GiM1_0`. My problem is that the column doesn't contain that specific string, only a part of it.

[Image of sql table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JSs3K.png)

So is there a way to **"search / look"** for `GiM1_0` and get `'GiM10_Integrated_testbed1'`. without removing the `_`? Maybe there is a way to see if some of the `GiM1_0` is found? They both have `GiM1`.

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: MariaDB is the database I'm useing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could remove underscores:

```
where replace(TestSuiteCollectionName, '_', ') LIKE concat('%', ?, '%')
```

The `?` is a *parameter placeholder*.  I encourage you to use parameters rather than munging query strings.

The above might match a few more things than you intend.

Alternatively, you could convert to a regular expression:

```
where TestSuiteCollectionName regexp replace(?, '_', '_?')
```

The question mark makes the `_` optional.  This is the narrowest answer to your question.